# Drupal cache not working - tables remain empty

Tags: caching, drupal

My problem is similar to these, but since I am not allowed to comment, I have to ask again:
a) [Drupal cache not working (tables empty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830258/drupal-cache-not-working-tables-empty)
b) [Drupal cache tables are empty, not receiving data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383912/drupal-cache-tables-are-empty-not-receiving-data)

I noticed that after I turned off the [Boost module](https://drupal.org/project/boost) and activated the "normal" Drupal cache, cache tables (starting with `cache_` in the database) are remaining empty. I read that this might be related to the use of the [Memcache module](https://drupal.org/project/memcache) which I used, too. But disabling that module doesn't change anything either.

I also suspected the [Elysia Cron module](https://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) to clear the cache every minute, but a) cache tables are always completely empty and b) `system_cron` just runs every hour.

Any more ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it *did* have to do with memcache: I had forgotten to remove the following line from my settings.php:

```
$conf['cache_inc'] = 'sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc';
```

After removing/uncommenting it, the cache tables are being filled.